# android crash : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1)

Tags: android, performance

My app crash sometimes. And there are only some lib error.I have more than 40,000 lines codes.I don't know how to find the bug? Is that the out of memory or use wrong method?

```
I/DEBUG   (  318): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadbaad
I/DEBUG   (  318): Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x760dafb8 passed to dlfree'
D/cta_dex (  998): conn HookConnectivityService onTransact code: 4
D/cta_dex (  998): conn pass onTransact code: 4
D/cta_dex (  998): conn HookConnectivityService onTransact code: 6
D/cta_dex (  998): conn pass onTransact code: 6
I/DEBUG   (  318):     r0 00000000  r1 4006f172  r2 deadbaad  r3 40072d5c
I/DEBUG   (  318):     r4 760dafb8  r5 4007d190  r6 41945000  r7 760dafc0
I/DEBUG   (  318):     r8 7a046b0c  r9 76090a64  sl 765716d0  fp 7a046b24
I/DEBUG   (  318):     ip 00000001  sp 7a046aa8  lr 4004088b  pc 4004088c      cpsr 60070030
I/DEBUG   (  318):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  318):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   (  318): 
I/DEBUG   (  318): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #00  pc 0001188c  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1191)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #01  pc 0000dd2b  /system/lib/libc.so (free+10)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #02  pc 00083943  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (CRYPTO_free+34)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #03  pc 00027035  /system/lib/libssl.so (SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos+16)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #04  pc 00008b7f  /system/lib/libjavacrypto.so
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #05  pc 0002034c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #06  pc 00050fcf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #07  pc 000297e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #08  pc 00030c6c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #09  pc 0002e304  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #10  pc 00063435  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #11  pc 00063459  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #12  pc 00058137  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  318):     #13  pc 0000d290  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
```

Answer (score 1):

SIGSEGV is legendary `Segmentation Fault Error`. You need to find mistake manually. Firstly check all calls to native (jni) libs or code resources. Including Android project code. Ie.: Once time I came across this signal when using cookie stores.

Comment: I have used this codes to blur the images:  ScriptIntrinsicBlur to blur the image.But how can i make sure which codes is used wrong?